# Multisite application with single sign in across domains in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, architecture, oauth

I have to develop multisite application with single sign on across domains (something like google account with multiple google services like gmail,docs,google+):

[image: multi applications, multi domains, single sign on]

- To use childen sites user must to sign up on parent site.
- Each site have its own logic except user sign in, points and
  invoices.
- From child application I must be able to sign in to global user
  account, spend user points and generate invoice for some service.
- Sign up form, listing of invoices and panel for managing points are
  avaiable only from parent site/application.

What is the best strategy for implementing this on Rails 3.1? Scalability, performance and security are important.

- Single or multiple rails applications?
- Single or multiple databases?
- Global services in main application or as a separate applications/engines?
- How to implement single sign in? Single session id in DB or something like facebook oauth?
- How to implement spending points and generating invoices as a result of request from child site?

Comment: From @david-sulc answer, with `@token.get('/customaction')` to receive custom data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to implement this using OmniAuth with multiple (and independent) Rails applications. These will be of interest:

- https://github.com/joshsoftware/sso-devise-omniauth-client
- https://github.com/joshsoftware/sso-devise-omniauth-provider

Blog post on the subject: http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2010/12/16/multiple-applications-with-devise-omniauth-and-single-sign-on/

Comment: Thanks, now how to implement requests to parentsite eg. "spend user points" method. Oauth2 has `@token.get('/customaction')`, it is appropriate?

Answer (score -1):

So lets say you create the Model `User` in the main application and migrate it. Then what you need to do is accessing this Datbase from the other Applications. That is no problem . First you need to add the Database Connection definition of the Main Application to the `config/database.yml` of the child application like this:

```
parent_connection:
  adapter: your_adapter_here
  host: your_host_here
  username: username
  password: password
  database: main_application_production
```

Then you create a Model called User but *not* with the scaffolder or sth. like this. Just create the file manually like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     establish_connection :parent_connection # This uses the specified connection
end
```

At the default case the connection selected is the one that matches the name of the environment. You only need to specify variations. So now you can access the `User` class like in the main application.

Comment: Ok, I know how to establish connection from model to selected DB, but this is a little part of whole problem. I need a solution/soft design pattern/strategy/model how to solve problem with scalability, performance and security.

Comment: -1, bad design to couple two apps on the line of a database.  use web services